# How to get from array of objects with property "name" array of strings (with names corresponding to each object)?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How having an array of objects with property "name" get array of strings (with names corresponding to each object)?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show a short example of what you expect the input and output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to select a specific property from each object in an array. If that property is called `Name` and is of type `string`, then you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = namedObjects.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP is looking for.  Except he wants an array.  If you update it to be an array, this is likely the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectWithNameString[] objects = ...?
string[] names = new string[objects.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = objects[i].Name;
}
```

For a better answer expand and clarify the question.